# Prove that $\int (\delta x)=\delta^{-d} \int f$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f$ be a real-valued integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^d$. Prove that $$\int f(\delta x) = \delta^{-d} \int f.$$

I let $f(x)=\chi_E(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }\delta x \in E \\ 0 & \text{if }\delta x \in E \end{cases} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \in \delta^{-1} E \\ 0 & \text{if } x \in \delta^{-1}E \end{cases}$.

Putting this together, I start with
\begin{align*}
m(\delta^{-1}E)&=\delta^{-d}m(E) \\
\sum_{k=1}^N a_k m(\delta^{-1}E)&=\delta^{-d} \sum_{k=1}^Na_km(E) \\
\end{align*}
And as $N \to \infty$, 
\begin{align*}
\int \chi_{\delta^{-1}E}(x)&= \delta^{-d} \int \chi_E(x) \\
\int f(\delta x) &= \delta^{-d} \int f(x).
\end{align*}
Is this correct?

Comment: For clarity, do you mean $\delta^{-1}E = \{\delta^{-1}x \; | \; x \in E\}$?

Comment: Why don't you just use the jacobian formula?

Comment: Mnifldz: Yes. mookid: That doesn't seem relevant to my study of integration theory (Chapter 2 of Stein-Shakarchi, Real Analysis)